Sync doors across server in Unity multiplayer game using Mirror
I'm trying to synchronize doors across the server for a multiplayer game using Unity and Mirror. The doors currently do synchronize across the server, however I do have a couple problems:
**If player 1 points at door 1 and player 2 at door 2, and one of the players presses OpenDoorKey, both doors will open.
If player 1 and player 2 point at door 1, and one of the players presses OpenDoorKey, the door will open and immediately close again.
**
Since I'm using raycasts in my door script, it should have to do with that. I have no idea how to fix this. Here's the code:
private void Update()
{
  if (isClient)
  {
    if (SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name == "Game")
    {
      crosshair = CrossHair.instance.crosshairImage;
    }

    RaycastHit hit;
    Vector3 fwd = playerCamera.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward);

    int mask = 1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer(excludeLayerName) | doorLayer.value;

    if (Physics.Raycast(playerCamera.position, fwd, out hit, rayLength, mask))
    {
      if (hit.collider.CompareTag(doorTag))
      {
        if (!doOnce)
        {
          CrosshairChange(true);
        }

        isCrosshairActive = true;
        doOnce = true;

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(openDoorKey))
        {
          doorIdentity = hit.collider.GetComponent<NetworkIdentity>();
          CmdDoorController(doorIdentity);
        }
      }
    }
    else
    {
      if (isCrosshairActive)
      {
        CrosshairChange(false);
        doOnce = false;
      }
    }
  }
}

[Command(requiresAuthority = false)]
private void CmdDoorController(NetworkIdentity doorIdentity)
{
  var doorController = doorIdentity.GetComponent<DoorController>();
  if (doorController != null)
  {
    doorController.PlayAnimation();
  }
}

Just like you can see in the code, I assign the doorIdentity variable locally only if openDoorKey is pressed, thinking this would make it work, which it didn't.
If you need anything else, please do ask. Thanks in advance.

This code is on the player or each door?
